# Using Laplace transforms to solve a differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, laplace-method

So I have been given this tricky problem...

We are supposed to use the laplace transform formulas:

$L[f']=sF(s)-f(0)$

or

$L[f'']=s^{2}F(s)-sf(0)-f'(0)$

to find $F(s)$ when $f(t)=te^{kt}+\cosh(t)$

>

Now, I THINK what we are supposed to do is to differentiate $f(t)$ so that you find

$f'(t)=kte^{kt}+\sinh(t);$

and

$f(0) = t+1;$

>

and then knowing what we do, sub it into $L[f']=sF(s)-f(0)$ so that we have:

$L[kte^{kt}+\sinh(t)]=sF(s)-(t+1)$

$\frac{k}{(s-k)^{2}}+\frac{1}{s^{2}-1}=sF(s)-(t+1)$

and then rearrange to find $F(s)$ so that:

$F(s) = \frac{k}{s(s-k)^{2}}+\frac{1}{s(s^{2}-1)}+\frac{1}{s}(t+1)$

what do you guys think??? yay or nay??? this seems a little too simple/easy and I feel like I am missing something... then again, I tend to over complicate things...

Comment: $f'(t)$ is not correct.

Comment: oh crap, I should have applied the product rule....

this is why I love you guys

Comment: Also, you might want to check what you wrote for $f(0)$.

Comment: so it turns out that

$f'(t)=kte^{kt}+e^{kt}+\sinh(t)$

which would mean that

$F(s)=\frac{k}{s(s-k)^{2}}+\frac{1}{s(s-k)}+\frac{1}{s(s^{2}-1)}+\frac{1}{s}(t+1)$

how'd I do this time???

Comment: See my previous comment on $f(0)$.

Comment: I dont understand....

$t*e^{k*0}=t*1=t$

and

$\cosh(0)=1$

am I missing something here???

Comment: What is $0 \times e^{^k \times 0}$?

Comment: ...............

it's a wonder that I am even able to breathe.....

so it turns out that $f'(t)=1$ and therefore

$F(s)=\frac{k}{s(s-k)^{2}}+\frac{1}{s(s-k)}+\frac{1}{s(s^{2}-1)}+\frac{1}{s}$

thanks for all of your help moo..... really appreciate it

Comment: You mean $f(0) = 1$, correct?

Comment: ahhh yeah, my bad... typo